# Objective-C equivalent of Actionscript code

Tags: objective-c, actionscript-3, porting

Can anyone help convert this this actionscript to Objective-c?

```
if(mcMain.y >= stage.stageHeight - mcMain.height)
{
    mainJumping = false;
    mcMain.y = stage.stageHeight - mcMain.height;
}
```

Specifically the stage.stageHeight and mcMain.height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing what `mcMain` and `stage` are, no, not easily. I assume that `stage` refers to the main drawing area; assuming that you are drawing within a `UIView` subclass, you can find the dimensions of the view by calling `bounds` upon the view:

```
CGRect bounds = self.bounds;
```

This will return a `CGRect`, which in itself is comprised of a `CGPoint`, called `origin`, and a `CGSize` called `size`; these are C-structs:

```
struct CGPoint {
    CGFloat x;
    CGFloat y;
};

struct CGSize {
    CGFloat width;
    CGFloat height;
};
```

To find the height of the `UIView`, you can do so quite simply:

```
CGFloat height = self.bounds.size.height;
```

Assuming that you are trying to find out the height of the view from within the view class itself.

I'm guessing that `mcMain` refers to some kind of image or object, so implementation of that is dependent on what it is. However, most co-ordinates rely on `CGRect`, `CGPoint` and `CGSize` in some way or another.

Answer (score 0):

If you're coming from the Flash world(like I did), then I highly recommend looking into the open source Cocos2D-iPhone framework: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/

I've rewritten your code in approximate Objective-C, just to give you an idea of what it might look like.

```
float stageHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
float guyHeight = mainGuy.contentSize.height;

if(mainGuy.position.y >= stageHeight - guyHeight)
{
    mainJumping = NO;
    mainGuy.position = ccp(mainguy.position.x, stageHeight-guyHeight);
}
```